# error 'long' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Tags: python, mysql

I don't know whats wrong with the attached code, it throws an error error 'long' object has no attribute 'fetchall'. Can some one help me out please.

Code:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. You shouldn't paste code as image, instead paste it as text so it can be easily manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `conn.execute` to `x.execute`.

Comment: I did but it throws the following error: TypeError: object of type 'long' has no len()

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'long' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.execute()` returns an int telling how many rows where affected (=>selected, inserted, deleted, updated...) by the SQL query, so you cannot chain the `.fetchall()` call, you need to do it in two steps:

```
x.execute("your query here")
rows = x.fetchall()
```

Comment: I did but it thows the following error:TypeError: object of type 'long' has no len()

Comment: Then you obviously didn't do it right. If you still assign the result of `x.execute()` (instead of the result of `x.fetchall()` to your (ill-named) XXX_cursor attributes the `len(self.XXX_cursor)` will (very obviously) fail. Please re-read my answer more carefully, take time to read the FineManual (all this is documented) and to try it out in a Python shell to make sure you get it right.